# Add fragment to specific view instance

Tags: android, view, append, fragment, childviews

Given a View instance like:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
```

Is it possible to add a fragment to this instance? Something like:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(view, R.id.myLinearLayout, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Notice the FragmentTransaction.add call. I want to add my fragment into the view instance, right in the R.id.myLinearLayout which is present in my R.layout.my_fragment and attached to the specific view instance.

I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
view.post(new Runnable {
    public void run() {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myLinearLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

So that once the view has been added to the layout the Runnable will run.

Comment: Will it add the fragment to the specific view instance?

Comment: Yes. It will add it to the view ID passed as first parameter to the transaction's add method.